# Keep the the "@" after selecting a username in jquery-mentions-input

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the jquery plugin "jquery-mentions-input", how could I make it so that when I choose the username that I want from the dropdown, the "@" remains in the textarea?

Right now if I type in "@UserN" and then click "username", the textarea will autocomplete to "username" but I want it to autocomplete to "@username".

Here's an example of this,

Before clicking the username: 
[image]

after clicking the username:

[image]

In this case I would like the text in the textarea to be "@admin", not "admin".

How could this be done?

Comment: do you mind using css ?

Comment: I would mind. I'm going to be parsing the usernames mentioned with "@" after the comment has been submitted in my controller.

Comment: Simply edit that plugin to do what you want. It's all open source.

Comment: try modifying your code so after onDataRequest function you add templates like so => onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {},templates: 'mentionItemSyntax'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `jquery.mentionsInput.js`, line 222:

I changed

```
var updatedMessageText = start + mention.value + ' ' + end;
```

to

```
var updatedMessageText = start + "@" + mention.value + ' ' + end;
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Just be careful not to update the package, otherwise you'll lose your changes.